# Does "sallow complexion" include bad meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, australian-english, racism

I'm non-native speaker and I live in Australia. When I filled out the form of a driving license, the officer made me fill sallow in the blank. I didn't know the meaning of sallow at that time, I did. Sallow means unhealthy, yellowish. I'm asian. Does it include racism? Or can be used often as describe complexion?

Comment: it does sound racist, you should report that officer.

Comment: It's a rarely-used word in the US, and I've generally taken it to agree with the basic dictionary definition -- sickly/jaundiced looking -- as it's almost always used to describe someone who is ill.

Comment: If the category was skin color, the officer likely nervously selected "sallow," as opposed to "yellow," "brown," or whatnot, in order to NOT sound racially offensive. What term would have been better? "Yellow"? "Brown"? If not, then what?

Comment: @curious-proofreader I don't know about other places, but in Maryland, the race category lumps a bunch of similar races together as categories. I'm part of the "WHITE, CAUCASIAN, ASIATIC INDIAN, ARAB" group

Comment: @Sam Lehman Sure. But what if in Australia they use "complexion" as a euphemism for race, so the category is "skin complexion." In that case, a nervous clerk might select anything OTHER than a color; or, what if the term is taken literally? Should the clerk then write something such as "lustrous," or "blemished," "pock-marked," or "spider-veined"?

Comment: I hope this clerk is on Xanax, probably has to answer this question a few dozen times a day.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled a) that an application form for a driving licence asked for details of skin colouring - don't you have to supply a photo anyway? and b) that an "officer" was on hand to help you fill it in. What exactly did the form ask for that "sallow" was the suggested answer? Reminds me of the visitor immigration form for the old apartheid South Africa where it asked for "race". Many a wag used to write "human".

Comment: what was the label for the blank?  race? ethnicity? skin color?

Comment: "sallow" for Asians is like "swarthy" for dark-skinned people.  You'd never use either in the us.

Comment: No… "sallow" is purely about appearance; not your "…ism".

Ask your search engine or even your good-old local library what "sallow" means but my justification is first that I was brought up with English as my first language and then that I spent 15 years or more working daily with police officers who very clearly used the term as a technical description; never anything else.

Comment: This is a word used on an official form from Australia. So answers should be addressing the meaning and context in Australia. Whatever disparagement there might be in the term 'sallow' is in the choice of that word by the official who wrote up the form.

Comment: I've added the 'Australian English' tag. One has to be careful to take into account the region / field where a word / expression is being used. Every dictionary I've checked in adds the 'unhealthy / sickly-looking' caveat, but they're all UK- or US-centric. Strine has its own peculiarities (as do all regional variants of English). When in Australia, use English as the Australians do. We really need a definition from an Australian-English dictionary. I'm guessing the 'sickly' caveat doesn't figure to an appreciable degree.

Answer (score 4):

In Ireland, we use it as a compliment. If you're not white as a sheet (like most of us) and have a slightly darker skin tone / can tan in the sun rather than burn, you might have sallow skin. There are a lot of Irish people in in Australia so maybe he meant it the same way. Hopefully, anyway.
I only learnt that it could mean jaundiced but we would just say jaundiced or yellow in that case.

Comment: Good deduction. Have you a reference or two showing the unmarked-for-sickness usage in Ireland, 444?

Answer (score 4):

I am in Australia and I have always used sallow for a desirable, healthy, olive, easily tanned complexion and not til now did I know it was defined as 'sickly'!! I have a lot of Irish ancestry, so my definition must have come from those influences.  I doubt it was intended to be racist.

Comment: Have you a definition from an Australian-English focused dictionary, 488? All the dictionaries usually cited here on ELU (they're mainly UK- and US-usage–driven) add the 'sickly / unhealthy-looking' caveat.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it was racist or anything.

I did a Google search and found a bunch of [death reports](https://books.google.com/books?id=4lNBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA536&lpg=PA536&dq=sallow+complexion+australia&source=bl&ots=MzV7OODwDq&sig=dr9Lb-8yr4IpH4u4fV6IG3mXopQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS6ffl1bvRAhVG2SYKHbgUB7EQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=sallow%20complexion%20australia&f=false) from *The South Australian Government Gazette, Volume 2* (1908). It seems 'sallow complexion' is a common description of many people. One guy named David Stuart jumps out to me because he's a 'Native of Scotland.'

A Google image search of 'sallow complextion' results of lots of white people's photos.

Perhaps you just have a sallow complexion. Reply with a photo of yourself maybe?

Comment: "*It seems 'sallow complexion' is a common description of many people.*" Of many **dead** people, yes.

Comment: @michael.hor257k not sure if joking or not, but check out James Lee. He's listed as sallow complexion, but his body was not found. So I highly doubt the complexions listed are for the dead bodies themselves.

Comment: I dunno. For me (a healthy-complexioned native of Scotland, as it happens) it's always meant *unhealthy* and a quick search backs me up, with most of the synonyms also referring to unhealthy people: sallow ˈsaləʊ/ adjective (of a person's face or complexion) of an unhealthy yellow or pale brown colour. "his skin was sallow and pitted" synonyms:yellowish, jaundiced, pallid, wan, pale, waxen, anaemic, bloodless, colourless, pasty, pasty-faced.

Comment: @flith Well, the context is Australia's vernacular.

Answer (score 2):

From doing genealogy, I noticed lots of older war draft forms in the US use words to describe skin color such as ruddy (red), sallow (yellow), white, light brown, dark brown, black. Some forms the color was hand written (1800s) and some preprinted where a check mark was used (1940s)

Comment: Sensible research. I'd guess, though, that the use of 'sallow' has dropped markedly in the US, but probably not in Australia.

Answer (score 1):

It is a coded way of saying that you don't look white enough to tick the `white` box. I don't know if Australian driving license forms collect data on race.

It is probably one of those terms invented to conceal or suppress accurate racial statistics.

I have an updated an answer at  https://english.stackexchange.com/a/459136/311500 over the origin and meanings of the word sallow.